# Spring Boot/Thymeleaf based large/mid scale application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

We are starting out with Spring Boot, and looking for best practices 
in implementing a large application. If you can provide links to any large/mid scale open source application 
implemented using Spring Boot, that would be helpful.

Also we did research code generated by "JHipster" (jhipster.github.io/) project, which 
definitely helps generating lot of boiler plate code like user management, transaction management, REST Services/ AngularJS based application.

The only problem is "JHipster" is AngularJS based. But in our case we 
would like to go with "Thymeleaf" based UI.

If you can provide a link to framework/sample application similar to "JHipster", 
but based on "Thymeleaf" based UI, that will also be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: http://spring.io is built on Spring Boot and uses Thymleaf. It's also open source: https://github.com/spring-io/sagan

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I was looking for Shopping cart/PetStore kind of application with features available in JHipster (User Management, DB/Transactions/, Liquibase config ...), that can be used as baseline for new Spring Boot Apps, based on Thymeleaf (non AngularJs).

Answer (score 1):

JHipster also supports Thymeleaf: by default it generates an AngularJS front-end, and this is its main goal, but you can also use Thymeleaf if you don't want a single Web page application.

If you have a look at the error pages, for example, they are done with Thymeleaf (as the 404 page can't be in the single Web page application, for obvious reasons)